# Can't connect arms to bones and seperated leg-bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

i just started with Blender and i tried to create a basic character to experiment with. I watched some tutorials about modelling and rigging and everything went fine, but when i tried to parent the mesh and armature an error ocurrs (Bone Heat Weighting). I googled a bit and managed to parent the head, legs and body to the armature. Only the arms are left. Also, the bones of the legs seem to be seperated. How can i fix these 2 problems ?

Here are some screenshot for visualization.

Object Mode:
[image]

Pose Mode:
[image]

Update 1: I fixed the problem with the legs, only the problem with he arms ia remaining

Update 2: Quad view

[image]

Bones:
I named them in German because it is easier for me.

1. Daumen = Thumb
2. Zeige = index
3. Mittel = middle
4. Ring = ring
5. Klein = pinky
6. Kopf = Head
7. OberSchenkel = UpperLeg
8. UnterSchenkel = LowerLeg
9. Fuß = foot

[image]

Comment: Please show the initial position before parenting mesh to armature with automatic weights.  You image should be similar to quad view so we can be sure all mesh vertices are very near one or at most two bones.  You can safely discard your previous work of (automatic weights) since it has failed.  You need to show more in your images such as the entire screen with information panels. Your mesh will be more readable when it is not gray be a distinctive color which contrasts the bone color.  Please also show edit mode with vertex weights showing for the expected controlling bone.

Comment: Please indicate an approximate count of how many times your have parented with automatic weights .... 1, 2, 3.  Again your image need to show more including how many meshes you have and the outliner window with hierarchy expanded.

Comment: You wrote [started with Blender] which I will call hence forth beginner work, I will assume low cost of beginner work and rework. Please back up your current flawed work. Remove all parenting and vertex groups. Start Fresh.   Inspect the position of the armature and the mesh, from all views left,right, top, bottom, front, back as in quad view.  Make sure the mesh is always near the armature.  Then  mesh to armature again.

Comment: Also state if your goal is to get a robotic solid inanimate movement or a fleshy pliable human movement.  Fleshy movement needs graduated weights.  Robotic solid movement can be fixed quickly keep a single bone influence and removing all other bone influences.   Since a serious armature video again will show you more detail I will not attempt a tutorial in words only.

Comment: Atm i am not on the computer but i want to provide some requested imformation: The initial position before parenting was/is the t-pose in the first picture. I read a post in another forum and the instruction was basically split your mesh and try again. It was assumed that the object consisted of multiple not connected parts. So now i have head, 2 arms, 2 legs and the body seperated (so 6 objects/meshes). Before that it failed entirely. I tried to parent it a couple of times, didn't count.

Comment: Actually it was a series of like 10 videos for beginners. (Modeling, rigging, material, animating, rendering). So my goal was to create a humanlike figure to experiment with animations. So i basically wanted to connect what i learned.

Comment: All readers can wait for you screen captures with words rather than words alone.